# A programmatic access to RPM apis/calls in golang

Tags: api, go, redhat, rpm

I'm struggling to find a native rpm binding for golang, all I found is [this](https://pypi.org/project/rpm) and a go [package](https://github.com/cavaliercoder/go-rpm).

A go package looks interesting but it fetches details from a rpm src package, which I don't have. I wanted to query rpm database at /var/lib/rpm/*

Need behaviour similar to,

1. `rpm -qa | grep NAME`
2. `rpm -qil NAME //for meta-data`

Please provide a pointer or suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik there is no native GO binding for rpm db. Feel free to ask rpm developers for it: https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/issues